# How to return a fetch result in a function

Tags: typescript, react-native

I want to return the result from fetch to another within this function to return the data to the origin call to this class and function. But I get this error: `Type 'Promise<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'String[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.`

```
export default class GetApiData {
    static getThemeParkData(): Array<String> {
        return fetch(
            url,
            {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
        )
        .then((response) => { 
            return response.json()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method returns a Promise, not an array. Fix the return type of your method.

Answer (score 0):

JB Nizet is right, you should change the return type of your method.

From `Array<String>` to `Promise<String[]>` or even `Promise<any>`

```
export default class GetApiData {
  static getThemeParkData(): Promise<any> {
    return fetch(
        url,
        {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }
    )
    .then((response) => { 
        return response.json()
    })
  }
}
```